# Inverse Labels in Py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I wonder how I can make inverse labels on one relationship. I know that having a bidirectional relationship is not recommended in Neo4j. I want to create something like the following.

`(MIT:Acronym)-[:IsExpandedTo]->(Massachusetts Institute of Technology:Term)`

I want to add an inverse label to the relationship such as IsAbbreviatedAs.

Comment: Well if you really want, you can have a relationship in both direction

Answer (score 1):

It is *bad practice* to always create a pair of relationships in opposite directions because it is totally unnecessary -- and therefore unnecessarily increases the complexity of your data model and code, and doubles the required data storage for the relationships.

Suppose you instead only created relationships of *one* type (say, `IsExpandedTo`), and in one direction:

```
CREATE (:Acronym {value: 'MIT'})-[:IsExpandedTo]->(:Term {value: 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'})
```

Then, to expand an acronym, you can do this:

```
MATCH (acronym:Acronym)-[:IsExpandedTo]->(term)
WHERE acronym.value = 'MIT'
RETURN term.value
```

And, to get an acronym (by going in the opposite direction), you can do this:

```
MATCH (acronym)-[:IsExpandedTo]->(term:Term)
WHERE term.value = 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'
RETURN acronym.value
```